# Search string as integer with Ransack in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I'm using the Ransack gem to set up a search form for a model. The model has a field `:size` which is stored as a string. I'd like to do a comparative search "using lte and gte". How can I cast this field as an integer when searching with ransack?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up a simple method that returns the length of the string?

```
def size_length
  size.length
end
```

Then your ransack could be something like `Model.search(:size_length_lteq => comparison)` ?

Also what about a custom matcher? Not sure if this will work, but might be something worth a shot.

```
# config/initializers/ransack.rb
Ransack.configure do |config|
  config.add_predicate 'string_lteq',
    arel_predicate: 'lteq',
    formatter: proc { |v| v.length },
    validator: proc { |v| v.present? },
    type: :string
end
```

Comment: I don't see how that would help. the length of "5" is 1, and the length of "9" is also 1.

Comment: Ah. so you actually have a number that is a string, not comparing strings to each other. Didn't catch that from your question.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the normal `lteq` and `gteq`? `"5" < "1" => false` should return correct even as strings, no need to cast them as int